# Which input/output stream is better to use to find a specific line on a source file on java?

Tags: java, c++

I wanted to create a data text file which stores username password etc of multiple users using a simple File writer class, and did. But I don't know which class to use to search,find and use them from the file I created. Help PLEASE?

Comment: Is your program a C++/Java hybrid?

Comment: Show us some code, what have you done so far? Also, why is `C++` tagged, it's a Java question?

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<your_file>));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
//process here
}
br.close();
```

This would be the standard way to read from a file.
Inside the while loop you could do things you need.

If you specify your question, more help will be possible